# Showing that the integral of an implicit function is $\pi^2/6 -1 = \zeta(2) -1$

Tags: calculus, integration

For $x \ge 1$, define $f(x) \in [0,1]$ implicitly by the equation $1 - f(x) = e^{-x f(x)}$.

Numerically, it seems that
$\int_1^\infty (1-f(x)) dx = \pi^2/6 - 1$.

How can I show this analytically?

This calculation arose in a problem I am studying on Erdős–Rényi random graphs -- thanks for the help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $y = f(x)$.  Then $$1-y = e^{-xy}$$ implies $$x = - \frac{\log (1-y)}{y},$$ which we can see is strictly increasing for $0 < y < 1$. Hence $$\int_{x=1}^\infty (1 - f(x)) \, dx = \int_{y=0}^1 - \frac{\log (1-y)}{y} - 1 \, dy = - 1 + \frac{\pi^2}{6}.$$
If the above is not quite clear, we insert some intermediate steps via Fubini's theorem:
$$\begin{align}
\int_{x=1}^\infty (1 - f(x)) \, dx &= \int_{x=1}^\infty \int_{y=f(x)}^1 1 \, dy \, dx \\
&= \int_{y=0}^1 \int_{x=1}^{-\log(1-y)/y} 1 \, dx \, dy \\
&= \int_{y=0}^1 - \frac{\log (1-y)}{y} - 1 \, dy.
\end{align}$$

Comment: It could have been interesting to be able to compute $$\int_1^\infty \frac{W\left(-e^{-x} x\right)}{x}\,dx$$

Comment: Thank you! I appreciated the extra calculations showing the exchange of integrals.